# Calls to Typescript setter don't return a function, although associated getter works

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm not sure why, but a setter I've written isn't being recognized when I call it.

Here's the error being thrown:

`TypeError: Bridge.Config.middleware is not a function`

Here's the typescript:

```
set middleware(val: any) { // should be function or function[]
  this.props.exceptions.middleware = val;
}
get middleware() {
  return this.props.exceptions.middleware;
}
```

Here's the generated JS:

```
Object.defineProperty(ConfigService.prototype, "middleware", {
    get: function () {
        return this.props.exceptions.middleware;
    },
    set: function (val) {
        this.props.exceptions.middleware = val;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

Testing:

```
// properly prints value
console.log(Bridge.Config.middleware);

// throws above-mentioned type error
Bridge.Config.middleware(fn);
```

How I'm Executing (compiling to es5): 
`tsc -w --module 'commonjs' --target 'es5'`

Comment: If it's a setter, you should set it like this: Bridge.Config.middleware = fn; you can set it, but you can't call it like a function

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it worked that. New to typescript. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a setter not a function.

Your code should be:

```
Bridge.Config.middleware = fn;
```